# Dell Laptop E6430 DVD Doesn't Work in Ubuntu 20.04 (Files and VLC) But Will Boot From BIOS

Tags: 20.04, dell, dvd

I can use USB booting no problem and in case it was a problem with the internal DVD drive I went ahead and bought another DVD drive only this time USB and external.  I can't play movies and this is the crux of the matter.  I have searched thru AskUbuntu, LinuxQuestions and I can't get an answer.  Can someone lead me in the right direction?  I have attempted to install everything that I have found and it installed as far as libraries are concerned and still nothing.  Thank you in advance.

---

I just installed Brasero just to see if maybe I would get a response over VLC and about the best that I can get is to eject the DVD.  The error message that I get from VLC when I hit "Play" from "Open Disc" is:

> Playback failure:
> DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0".
> Your input can't be opened:
> VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.

`/dev/sr0` does exist.  I am at a loss.

Comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For DVD-Video playback in any internal or external drive you need the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse   #only needed if the multiverse repository isn't enabled
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

Use TAB then cursor keys to navigate and answer "OK" in the following screens. Then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

and again use TAB and cursor keys to navigate and answer "Yes" to the following screens.
Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

In Ubuntu 20.04 you may find an error about a missing `libdvdread7` library. Install it:

```
sudo apt install libdvdread7
```

Lastly, you may want to install VLC. And for good measure install adiitonal codecs and fonts (important for other media players; VLC uses its own set of codecs):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

(NOTE: Use `xubuntu-restricted-extras` for Xubuntu and `lubuntu-restricted-extras` for Lubuntu.)

Comment: I went thru these steps, again, and Ubuntu came back with already installed messages.  Thank you for answering.  Would you have any other helpful ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: It couldn't have said "already installed" to commands that weren't installing anything, like `dpkg-reconfigure`... That said, if you actually followed this steps and DVD video doesn't work that means either the drives are faulty or the disk is. Also please do not use the answers field for comments. Media files have little to nothing to do with reading from optical media.

Comment: The `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` command (almost: it was in fact `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-addons`) is what finally got my new 20.04 machine to play my DVDs. Thanks.

Comment: @PatJ Thank you but, again, that codecs package has nothing to do with playing DVD-Video which is a standard industry format with a standard video codec inside a standard file structure. You may have DVD-ROM with video files inside and, of course, those can be anything except a DVD-Video (think about a CD-ROM with MP3 files which ISN'T a CD-Audio).